# function based on other callBack function... react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

when user wants to to POST somthing he must be singed in(without username & pass). 
Problem is i'm trying to make when CreatePost() invoked it will call SingUser() and based on SingUser() fetch request it will call CreatePost() again to let user post after he sign in.

this is in createpost component

```js
CreatePost(){
    fetch(url ,{
      method :'POST',
      headers:{
        Accept:'application/json',
        'Content-Type' :'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(post)
   }).then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson)=>{
      if(responseJson.status =='inactive'){
               //SignUser
      }else{
             //post
      }
  }).catch((error)=>{ //later
  });
}
```

here is SingUser() in other file

```js
async function SignUser() {
           try{
          User.vtoken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('vtoken');
          var userTemp={
            vtoken: User.vtoken,
            ntoken : User.ntoken
            }
                fetch(url,{
                    method :'POST',
                    headers:{
                      Accep : 'application/json',
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(userTemp)
                  }).then((response)=> response.json()).
                then((responseJson)=>{
                        if(responseJson.path == 2){
                            Save(responseJson, userTemp);}
                            else return;
                  }).catch((error)=>{
                     });
            
       }catch(error){}
}

async function Save(result , userTemp){
    try{
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('vtoken', result.vtoken);
            User.vtoken = result.vtoken;
            userTemp.vtoken = result.vtoken;

          fetch(url,{
            method :'POST',
            headers:{
              Accep : 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(userTemp)
          }).then((response)=>response.json()).
          then((responseJson)=>{
              return 'done';
          }).catch((error)=>{})
      }
      catch(error){}
}
export {SignUser}
```

i hope u understand what im trying to do if there is better way to do it thnx:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve it, I did little adjustments

```js
async CreatePost(){
   try{
     var response = await fetch(url ,{
      method :'POST',
      headers:{
        Accept:'application/json',
        'Content-Type' :'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(post)});
      var responseJson = await response.json();
      if(responseJson.status =='inactive' && postRepeat == true){
               postRepeat == false;
                await SignUser();
                this.CreatePost();
      }
       else{
        //posted
      }
}catch(err){}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
const errorCodeMap = {
  USER_INACTIVE: 10,
}

const statusMap = {
  INACTIVE: `inactive`
}

const METHOD = `POST`
const APPLICATION_JSON = `application/json`

const headerDefault = {
  Accept: APPLICATION_JSON,
  'Content-Type': APPLICATION_JSON,
}

const who = `post`

async function createPost(payload, options) {
  try {
    const {
      url = ``,
      fetchOptions = {
        method: METHOD,
        headers: headerDefault,
      },
    } = options
    const {
      post,
    } = payload

    const response = await fetch(url, {
      ...fetchOptions,
      body: JSON.stringify(post)
    })

    const {
      status,
      someUsefulData,
    } = await response.json()

    if (status === statusMap.INACTIVE) {
      return {
        data: null,
        errors: [{
          type: who,
          code: errorCodeMap.USER_INACTIVE,
          message: `User inactive`
        }]
      }
    } else {
      const data = someNormalizeFunction(someUsefulData)

      return {
        data,
        errors: [],
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {

  }
}

async function createPostRepeatOnInactive(payload, options) {
  try {
    const {
      repeat = 1,
    } = options

    let index = repeat
    while (index--) {
      const { data, errors } = createPost(payload, options)

      if (errors.length) {
        await signUser()
      } else {
        return {
          data,
          errors,
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {

  }
}
```